# Is there a way to modify an EBS volume through AWS Lambda ? (Boto3)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I want to modify my ebs volume through an AWS Python Lambda script.
I am looking through boto3 documentation, but I could not find anything about EBS volume modification. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boto3 AWS SDK for Python has a [`modify_volume()` function](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.modify_volume) that can modify volume size, volume type, and IOPS capacity:

```
response = client.modify_volume(
    DryRun=True|False,
    VolumeId='string',
    Size=123,
    VolumeType='standard'|'io1'|'gp2'|'sc1'|'st1',
    Iops=123
)
```

This can be called from an AWS Lambda function written in Python.